# SQL: How to apply distinct only for one column out of many?

Tags: sql, distinct

I have two tables `Orders` and `Customers`. `Orders` contains the following columns: `OrderID`, `CustomerID`. `Customers` contains columns: `CustomerID`, `CustomerName`. I have a few records from `Customers` which do not have any orders. So I want to get all unique customers (even they do not have orders) and orders.

I want to get it by using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CustomerName) OrderID, Orders.CustomerID, CustomerName
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

But it replace `OrderID` column values by `CustomerName` values.
That why I should use the following query to get the desired result.

```
SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, CustomerName
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT(CustomerName) OrderID, Orders.CustomerID, CustomerName
    FROM Customers
    LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
    ORDER BY CustomerName
);
```

Is there any errors into my first query? Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: First advice, you miss a comma "," after the select Distinct(CustomerName) , OrderID,

Comment: Distinct works per row only. What would you expect to see for a customer that has more than one order?

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's just an example query. I know that it is meaningless, but I want to get all unique customers. I know that one customer can get more than one order.

Comment: Check out Darren's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OrderID` will return more than one record when a customer has more than one order.
`DISTINCT` works on whole records, not individual fields so if there's more than one order for a customer it will show both records - the customer will be the same, but the order id is different so both records will be distinct.

If you `COUNT` the OrderID and `Group` the `CustomerName` you'll get unique customers and how many orders they've made:

```
SELECT CustomerName, COUNT(OrderID) AS Count_Of_Orders
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY CustomerName
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

[image]

Comment: If you do only want customer names you could just use `SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers`

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(CustomerName) as CusName, OrderID, Orders.CustomerID
    FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = 
    Customers.CustomerID ORDER BY CusName;
```

You are using the Customer name two times and actually OrderId is in your case then the alias column name of CustomerName :)

Comment: Your query does not return unique customers. I have duplicates in the result. You can try it in w3schools sql editor.

Comment: sorry dear, got you wrongly, you didn't mention in your question that you want the number of orders as per EACH customer. Anyway, Darren's answer is the one!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand that if you want OrderId col it means that if you'll have more than one Order per customer - it will duplicate the rows.
so you have to choose: or distinct row per customer or show orderId you cannot have them both! (this is a logical issue not SQL fault)
anyways you have to use LEFT OUTER JOIN in order to see Customers with no orders.

one option is to count the orders:

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, COUNT(0) AS NumOfOrders
FROM Customers C
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders O ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CustomerName
ORDER BY C.CustomerName;
```

The other option is to allow duplications:

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, O.OrderID
FROM Customers C
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders O ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
ORDER BY C.CustomerName;
```